# Transformations on rational functions where x is in the numerator and denomiator.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem was to plot $ f(x) = \frac{x-2}{x-1} $ using transformations.

There are samples and videos online on transforming simpler rational functions like:

$$ y = \frac{1}{x} $$

and that easy to understand. But nothing this complex.

In this case, though, what is the parent function to transform **from**?

How does one even start with this?

Comment: Notice that $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x-1}$

Comment: @anorton I wrote it as an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Notice that $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{x-1}$. Then starting from $y=\frac{1}{x}$ the first transformation moves the graph along x-axis and the second moves the graph along the y-axis.

Comment: To sum up, $$ y = \frac{1}{x} $$ is, in fact, the parent function.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, the following is a breakdown of the operartions involved:-

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

f(x) is transformed to g(x) where g(x) = f(x – 1). [= Right shifting f(x) by 1 unit]

g(x) is then transformed to h(x) where h(x) = –g(x). [= reflecting g(x) about the x-axis]

h(x) is then transformed to k(x) where k(x) = 1 + h(x). [= Up shifting h(x) by 1 unit.]